# OpenLDAP migrate from 2.3 to 2.4 ldapsearch ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Tags: openldap

I am migrating a working OpenLDAP 2.3.43 setup to OpenLDAP 2.4.44 on a new RHEL server.  I have copied the data using slapcat and successfully imported using slapadd.  A ldapsearch that works on 2.3 does not work on 2.4 and produces a ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49).  Here is the relevent parts of the slapd.conf:

```
access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
access to *
    by self write
by users read
by anonymous read


database    bdb
cachesize       10000
suffix          "o=itsso"
checkpoint      128 5


rootdn         "cn=admin,o=itsso"
rootpw          {CRYPT}55qEg16ldm0Bo


index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber,loginShell    eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
```

Here is the ldapsearch command:

```
ldapsearch -h localhost -D "cn=admin,o=itsso" -W -b o=itsso -s sub mail="first.last@xyz.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at https://ltb-project.org/documentation/general/migrate_slapd_conf_cn_config

Even though I had /etc/openldap/slapd.conf openldap 2.4 starts using /etc/openldap/slapd.d.

I found a work around if I deleted /etc/openldap/slapd.d and then the slapd.conf file gets used when starting slapd.  However, I decided to convert slapd.conf to cn=config.

Here is what I did:

```
service slapd stop
mv /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ /etc/openldap/slapd.d.bak
mkdir /etc/openldap/slapd.d
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -d 256
chown -R ldap.ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d
service slapd start
```